# Modify a button label in dynamics crm

Tags: dynamics-crm, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2013

In my associated view pages of some entities,  i want to modify some button labels.

For masculine noun entities I want to have:

- Ajouter une nouveau "NameOfEntity"

and for feminine noun entities I want to have:

- Ajouter une nouvelle "NameOfEntity"

how can i change the button label, knowing it is a system button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit almost any button label. A really useful tool to do this is [RibbonWorkbench](http://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/71374-1-getting-started-with-the-ribbon-workbench)

If you want to edit the button labels for certains entities, you will need to have a solution with the entities you want to modify, open that solution with Ribbon Workbench and found the button to change.

If you want to made the change globally I think you will need to add the application ribbon to the solution.